# How to use Python drawing line in a picture?

Tags: python

I have the following question:

Draw a green vertical line 1/3 of the way from the left edge, and a horizontal blue line 1/3 from the top. The vertical line should extend from the top of the image to the bottom; the horizontal line should extend from the left edge to the right edge. Using a loop and draw the lines pixel by pixel.

Draw a green vertical line from top to bottom, 1/3 of the way across a copy of `edinburgh-castle.gif`; also draw a horizontal blue line 1/3 of the way down the same image. Return the copy.

Thanks guys...I have really no idea how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should visit stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to make better questions and increase chances of getting better responses

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw lines onto an image in a file, I would probably recommend you use the pygame library. It works fairly well for this sort of processing.

You can use the pygame.image.load() function to load the image as a Surface object, then use pygame.draw.line() function to draw the line onto the surface. Then you can save the modified surface back into the file with pygame.image.save().

Here are the pygame docs:

https://www.pygame.org/docs/

And if you haven't used it before you can download it right here:

http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml